# Deserialization of Json in ashx handler

Tags: asp.net, json

I am trying to deserialize my json data in handler see this:

```
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    var data = context.Request;
    var sr = new StreamReader(data.InputStream);
    var stream = sr.ReadToEnd();
    var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    var asd = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<objEnt>(stream);
```

i am getting the correct values in stream: like

```
 "{\"objEnt\":{\"EventName\":\"uyiouioui\",\"EventId\":0,\"Active\":\"1\",\"CountryId\":5,\"StateId\":7,\"CityId\":6,\"Contact\":\"uio\",\"EventVenue\":\"uio\",\"Address\":\"uio\",\"Status\":true,\"Longitude\":\"89\",\"Latitude\":\"89\",\"ShortDesc\":\"ouioui\",\"EventDesc\":\"ouiouio\",\"EventCategoryId\":7,\"StartDate\":\"6/7/2014\",\"EndDate\":\"2014-06-13T18:30:00.000Z\",\"errors\":[],\"FileName\":\"/NightlifeSite/NightlifeClientuploads/Events/\",\"StartTime\":\"12:00 AM\",\"EndTime\":\"12:00 AM\",\"StateName\":\"Karnatka\",\"CityName\":\"Banglore\",\"CountryName\":\"India\",\"EventCategoryName\":\"sadfaewyu\"}}"
```

But this values are not rendering in my 'asd' Everytime the count is zero only!!

my objEnt class is like:

```
     [Serializable]
    public class objEnt
    {
        public List<EventEntity> obj { get; set; }

    }


     [Serializable]
   public  class EventEntity:Base
    {

      public string EventName { get; set; }
      public string FileName { get; set; }
      public int EventId { get; set; }
      public int CountryId { get; set; }
      public int StateId { get; set; }

        |
        |
        |
        more
```

It is really getting confusing with DTO classes

Comment: Have you tried using JSON.NET? Its much better than the default serializer provided.

Answer (score 0):

Using JSON.NET you can try something like this

```
var asd  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<objEnt>(stream);
```